# Resizing images JavaScript/jQuery without losing quality

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a way to resize images with JavaScript or jQuery without losing the quality of the image. I have found solutions using PHP but I am not a server-side programmer.

I am trying to develop a portfolio website for me and a friend and I created a lightbox effect. The problem arives when the website examples get clicked; their original size shrinks to 55% width and 90% height so that they have a decent view in all resolutions.

On monitors of 1366x768 the photos start looking very pixelated but on bigger resolutions they are ok.

Here is my website:

[Foxteam.net](http://www.foxteam.net/portfolio.php)

So can anyone tell of a solution for this problem?

Comment: Have you tried the image-rendering CSS property? https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Image-rendering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is to render different versions of the image server-side using proper image manipulation tools. Serve-up the appropriate size depending on the user's screen size.

Depending on the browser to size the image will never have consistent and high-quality results.

Comment: +1 Also, it saves you serving a 4096 px wide image to 600 px wide monitor (bandwidth optimization).